# Swift - Ternary conditional operator misunderstanding

Tags: ios, swift, ternary-operator

I have issues understanding something with ternary conditional operator in Swift 4.1. I hope someone can explain to me :)

I'm using Apollo library.
This library exposes me an object with this field (EDIT) :

```
public var discount: Swift.Optional<Bool?> {
    get {
      return graphQLMap["discount"] as! Swift.Optional<Bool?>
    }
    set {
      graphQLMap.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "discount")
    }
}
```

In my class, I'm trying to set this value to `true` or `nil` (if value is `false`, it should be `nil` to return all results).

Attempt #1 :

```
func setGoodDeals(_ goodDeals: Bool) {
    filters.discount = goodDeals ? goodDeals : nil;
}
```

This doesn't work ; my app crashes with this error :

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional'
>   (0x10a9fa298) to 'Swift.Bool' (0x10a9cddf8).

Attempt #2 :

```
if ( goodDeals ) {
    filters.discount = goodDeals;
} else {
    filters.discount = nil;
}
```

This works.

Attempt #3 :

```
func setGoodDeals(_ goodDeals: Bool) {
    filters.discount = goodDeals ? true : nil;
}
```

This works.

Can anyone explain to me why ?

Thx in advance,

Comment: Are you sure the type of `discount` is `Swift.Optional<Bool?>` ? This means it's a "double-optional bool", or `Swift.Optional<Swift.Optional<Bool>>`, which makes little sense. Also I just ran your code in Attempt #1 with both Xcode 9 and 10 beta and it compiles and run fine.

Comment: Apart from the question this is Swift: No trailing semicolons!

Comment: Thx for your help. @Guillaume, yep it's a copy-paste from the file generated by Apollo. Did you test with an double optional bool ? Because I'm started to think that Apollo is messing with swift...

Comment: @vadian, I prefer to keep semicolons :) I like to see when an instruction is finished, especially when the line breaks. i'm maybe i'm old school ... :P

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Your Attempt #1 code works fine (though this is a bizarre type that is likely to bite you often). What is the stack trace? Remember, this is `Optional<Optional<Bool>>`. So true is actually `.some(.some(true))`. For false do you want `.some(nil)` or `nil`? I suspect you have code somewhere else that assumes this is `.some(nil)` rather than `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, the double-optional values kind of got me loose my temper ^^! Aaaaaaah, I just realize that I may have missed some details on my post. That could explain why you cannot reproduce this because it's not a simple get/set value. Apollo's objects are dictionaries... I think I'm gonna blame Apollo for this cause it seems to work for you...

Answer (score -2):

Very simple. It works like this.

Let's say we have to pas the string on the basis of a bool 'isNewUser'.

yourLable.text = isNewUser ? "You can get" : "You get"

if 'isNewUser' is true then it will pass "You can get otherwise it will pass "You get".

I hope it is crystal clear.

Comment: This seems to be clear to the person asking from the start and is not helping answering the question.

Comment: I thought clearing the base concept can help to solve the question.